# How can I get the wl driver to work?

Tags: wifi

Wifi works with the live USB. But once installed, I get nothing. I tried to `sudo modprobe wl`, but I get a message that says

> Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.-32-generic.

It's a XPS 9343.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by using my iPhone as a personal hotspot (plugged in not wireless). Then I ran the software updater, it picked up on the Broadcom drivers. I installed it, rebooted and now my WiFi works.